# Android app crashes on mobile device but runs on Eclipse!

Tags: android, sqlite, crash

I am developing an android app that uses sqlite to store some data. It consists of two tables, one that holds a username and password and another that holds 10 integers. 
On eclipse it works perfectly but on my mobile phone crashes when I want to write in the second table. Is there any way to find why it crashes on my mobile? I ran it with the debugger on eclipse but there wasn't any errors.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is:

> How can I debug my Android application on a phone?

Then read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).